# How to achieve matching with same table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, self

I want to count number of sites partition by country on the basis of below criteria:-

For each TrialSite with Trial_Start_Date = X and Site_Activated = Y, you should be counting all rows that meet these conditions:

- Trial_Start_Date <= Y, AND
- TrialSite_Activation_Date >= X
  i.e. all rows where there is some overlapping period with that row's Trial Start Date to TrialSite Activation Date.

sample data example:

```
Trial id  start_date  country  site_id trialSite_activation_date

Trial A    01-01-2017  India  site1 01-02-2017 ----> 2 (only overlaps with itself, and with 2nd row)

Trial A  01-01-2017  India  site 2 01-04-2017 ----> 4 (overlaps with all rows, including itself)

Trial B    02-03-2017 India  site3 01-04-2017 ----> 3 (does not overlap with first row, since Trial_Start_Date > 01-02-2017)

Trial B   02-03-2017 India  site4 01-04-2017 ----> 3
```

This data can contain multiple countries and this logic needs to be applied with same country records.

Comment: show the query you constructed so far please

Comment: I was unable to construct the query for this so asked in this forum for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the “overlaps” operator `&&` on `daterange`s:

```
SELECT t1, count(*)
FROM trial t1
   JOIN trial t2
      ON daterange(t1.trial_start_date, t1.trialsite_activation_date, '[]')
         && daterange(t2.trial_start_date, t2.trialsite_activation_date, '[]')
GROUP BY t1;

                      t1                       | count
-----------------------------------------------+-------
 ("Trial A",2017-01-01,India,site1,2017-02-01) |     2
 ("Trial A",2017-01-01,India,site2,2017-04-01) |     4
 ("Trial B",2017-03-02,India,site3,2017-04-01) |     3
 ("Trial B",2017-03-02,India,site4,2017-04-01) |     3
(4 rows)
```

Instead of using the whole-row reference `t1` in the `SELECT` list, you can specify individual columns there, but then you gave to list them in the `GROUP BY` clause as well.

Comment: I am getting the below error :- ERROR:  range lower bound must be less than or equal to range upper bound. Also, if country partition needs to be taken as different countries are present in the actual data and this match should be done with other rows of only that particular country.. Also, one point there are some null entries in dates as well.

Comment: Well, with an inexact question you'll get an inexact answer. If your lower bounds and upper bounds are inverted, try `LEAST` and `GREATEST` on them to order them. If you don't want to match all entries with all other entries, specify additional conditions in the `ON` clause. If you have `NULL` values, specify how they should be handled. In short, provide a dataset that shows all your requirements.

Comment: Hi Laurenz, Thank you so much for this!, I have tested the query and it is working perfectly for the cases where start_date <= trialsite_activation_date but fails for start_date > trialsite_activation_date. I have put the sample date, please could you help me in this final case as well.